# Как сделать плавную анимацию <canvas> изменения длины линии окружности

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

Мне нужно сделать **плавную** анимацию увеличения длины линии окружности. Я использую `<canvas>`, но он не работает должным образом. Также я использую ReactJS + Two.js.

---

Sandbox демо анимации:
https://1jxhv.csb.app/
Sandbox код: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-lalande-1jxhv?file=/src/App.js

---

Код:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import Two from "two.js";

let two;
let stop = 100;
export default () => {
  let gameRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    two = new Two({ width: 310, height: 310 }).appendTo(gameRef.current);

    setInterval(() => {
      if (stop > 0) {
        two.update();
        stop = stop - 1;
        draw();
      }
    }, 1000 / 30);
  }, [gameRef]);

  const draw = () => {
    let points = [];
    let centerX = 155;
    let centerY = 155;
    let radius = 150;
    let steps = 100;

    for (var i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
      if (i > stop)
        points.push(
          new Two.Anchor(
            centerX + radius * Math.cos((2 * Math.PI * -i - 160) / steps),
            centerY + radius * Math.sin((2 * Math.PI * -i - 160) / steps)
          )
        );
    }

    two.clear();

    let path = two.makeCurve(points, true);

    path.noFill().linewidth = 5;
    path.cap = path.join = "round";
    path.stroke = "black";
  };

  return (
    <div className="game-container col">
      <div ref={gameRef} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: причем тут canvas, если сейчас используется svg?

Comment: Суть вопроса от этого не меняется

Comment: Вообще меняется, так как подходы при работе с svg и canvas могут отличаться.

Answer (score 0):

1. Для анимаций рекомендуется `requestAnimationFrame`.
2. Если оставите `setInterval`, возвращайте из `useEffect` callback с `clearInterval`
3. canvas часто не тормозит там, где тормозит svg